# oracle: unable to open log file error

Tags: oracle

So, i have a file `A.txt`

```
ENG,England,English
SCO,Scotland,English
IRE,Ireland,English
WAL,Wales,Welsh
```

i wish to load to an oracle `EXTERNAL TABLES`. So this is all the things that i did up til now.

```
CREATE DIRECTORY LOCAL_DIR AS 'C:/Directory/'
GRANT ALL ON DIRECTORY LOCAL_DIR TO ruser;
```

I then pasted `A.txt` at `C:/Directory/`

Then i executed following query:

```
CREATE TABLE countries_ext (
  country_code      VARCHAR2(5),
  country_name      VARCHAR2(50),
  country_language  VARCHAR2(50)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL (
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY LOCAL_DIR
  ACCESS PARAMETERS (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
      country_code,country_name,country_language
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('Countries1.txt')
)
PARALLEL 5
REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;
```

It showed `Table Created.`

But when i try to execute the query:

`SELECT * FROM countries_ext;` I get following exception:

```
Unable to open file countries_ext_5244.log. The location or file does not exist.
```

Could someone tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `c:\directory` on the server the database is on, or on your client PC (if they are different)?

Comment: Hi, `C:\directory` is on the server db is on and not on a remote machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created your directory like this:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY LOCAL_DIR AS 'C:/Directory/'
```

But according to [the Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5008.htm#SQLRF01207)
the path does not include a trailing slash.

---

> " can `external tables` be also used with files that are in remote machines?"

We can create directory objects against any OS directory which is addressable from the database server. So the remote machine must be mapped to a drive on the database server.

There are several issues with this. The first is that in my experience DBAs are reluctant to have their database dependent on other servers, especially ones outside their control. The second is performance: external tables cannot be tuned like heap tables, because they are just files on the local OS. Performance against a remote file will definitely be worse, because of network latency. Which brings us to the third issue, the network admin who will be concerned about the impact on the network of queries executing against a remote file. I'll be honest, I have never seen external tables being used against remote files.

Which isn't to say it can't work. But whether it's the best solution depends on how large the file is, how often you're going to query it, the capacity of your network and what your reasons are for not hosting the file on the database server.

Comment: I checked without adding trailing slash, but that does not seem to be the problem

Comment: Thanks for the solution. You were right. Forgive my ignorance, but can `external tables` be also used with files that are in remote machines. Or if `external tables ` is not possible, is there any other viable alternative?